# How to split a text file into a nested array?

Tags: python

Working on a project creating a python flask website that stores user logins into a text file. I have a text file where each line is one user and each user has 5 parameters stored on the line. All user parameters are separated by a `;` character.

Parameters are:

```
username
password
first name
last name
background color
title
avatar
```

Sample of the text file:

```
joebob;pass1;joe;bob;yellow;My title!!;https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/cd/Stick_Figure.jpg
richlong;pass2;rich;long;blue;My title2!!;https://www.iconspng.com/images/stick-figure-walking/stick-figure-walking.jpg
```

How do I go about storing the parameters into a python array, and how do I access them later when I need to reference log-ins.

Here is what I wrote so far:

```
accounts = { }
def readAccounts():
    file = open("assignment11-account-info.txt", "r")
    for accounts in file: #line
        tmp = accounts.split(';')
        for data in tmp: #data in line
            accounts[data[0]] = {
                'user': data[0],
                'pass': data[1],
                'first': data[2],
                'last': data[3],
                'color': data[4],
                'title': data[5],
                'avatar': data[6].rstrip()
            }
        file.close()
```

Comment: Your username is unique??

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I might do:

```
accounts = {}
with open("assignment11-account-info.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    fields = line.rstrip().split(";")
    user = fields[0]
    pass = fields[1]
    first = fields[2]
    last = fields[3]
    color = fields[4]
    title = fields[5] 
    avatar = fields[6]
    accounts[user] = {
      "user" : user,
      "pass" : pass,
      "first" : first,
      "last" : last,
      "color" : color,
      "title" : title,
      "avatar" : avatar
    }
```

By using `with`, the file handle `file` is closed for you automatically. This is the most "Python"-ic way of doing things.

So long as `user` is unique, you won't overwrite any entries you put in as you read through the file `assignment11-account-info.txt`.

If you need to deal with a case where `user` is repeated in the file `assignment11-account-info.txt`, then you need to use an array or list (`[...]`) as opposed to a dictionary (`{...}`). This is because reusing the value of `user` will overwrite any previous `user` entry you add to `accounts`. Overwriting existing entries is almost always a bad thing when using dictionaries!

If that is the case, I might do the following:

```
accounts = {}
with open("assignment11-account-info.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    fields = line.rstrip().split(";")
    user = fields[0]
    pass = fields[1]
    first = fields[2]
    last = fields[3]
    color = fields[4]
    title = fields[5] 
    avatar = fields[6]
    if user not in accounts:
      accounts[user] = []
    accounts[user].append({
      "user" : user,
      "pass" : pass,
      "first" : first,
      "last" : last,
      "color" : color,
      "title" : title,
      "avatar" : avatar
    })
```

In this way, you preserve any cases where `user` is duplicated.

Comment: The lookup is definitely better with this dictionary store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python builtin csv to parse

```
import csv

with open("assignment11-account-info.txt", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
    result = []
    for row in reader:
        fields = ('user', 'passwd', 'first', 'last', 'color','title','avatar')
        res = dict(zip(fields, row))
        result.append(res)
```

Or equivalent but harder to read for a beginner the pythonic list comprehension:

```
with open("assignment11-account-info.txt", "r") as file:
        reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
        fields = ('user', 'passwd', 'first', 'last', 'color','title','avatar')
        result = [ dict(zip(fields, row)) for row in reader ]
```